# Creating an instance for other class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have no idea how I should correctly name the title but I know exactly what my problem is (I will eventually edit the title later).

I am pretty new to Objective-C and I am still learning.

So, I have a class that contains a tableView (I will call it ClassA) and another with a normal UIView (ClassB). What I want to do, is to let a button appear when a row is selected.

I created in my ClassB.h file:

```
+(id)sharedInstance;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
-(void) showBtn :(BOOL) show;
```

And in my ClassB.m file:

```
@synthesize btn;

static ClassB *this = nil;

(+id) sharedInstance {

    if(!this) {
        @synchronized (self) {
            this = [[ClassB alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return this;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [self showBtn:NO] //because I only want to let it appear when a row is selected.
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}

-(void) showBtn :(BOOL) show { // I called this method in classA.


    if (show == NO) {
        btn.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        btn.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

So when I launch my app, the button is hidden and stays hidden when I select a row. I debugged, and found that btn is nil when I called the method in ClassA. After some research, I found that the method is called for another instance, so here my question, what can I do, to get it called for the right instance?

**EDIT**

Here part of my ClassA.m

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger   row = [indexPath row];

    [[ClassB sharedInstance] showBtn:YES];
}
```

Comment: You are adding the method `showBtn` to the view which is impossible. You probably mean `[self.view addSubview: btn];` Using less cryptic names can avoid those mistakes.

Comment: how are you creating instance ?

Comment: Sorry, was a typing mistake. It is btn. I simplified the names here to make them more general

Comment: Please paste your code of class A. How you are accessing Class B in class A.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu added ClassA.

Comment: You are using the shared instance on B viewController thats why you are getting instance of button as nil. The IBOutlets of ViewController are initialize when the view didLoad of B is called , mostly when they are visible to user.You can do one thing , create a variable in class B isButtonVisible and assign it's value in Class A , this way Whenever B's ViewController is loaded you will get the desired result. Hope this helps you out!!

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu I tried this already but without success

Answer (score 0):

**Observation:** The ClassB is a UIViewController which is wrong. `UIViewControllers` have `viewDidLoad`.

**Implementation Suggestion:**

The correct implementation for the requirement would be that you create a custom cell with a button. Hide the button in `awakeFromNib` method. in `didSelectRowAtIndex` set the `cell.button.isHidden = YES`.

This should alone take care of the requirement mentioned above.

Comment: The thing is, ClassA is in a container View of ClassB and the button should be in ClassB